# Best method to temporarily store/query data?

Tags: java

I have an application that stores information about user temporarily. I don't want to mess with mysql because it's overkill - I need to store an id, user name, and some additional fields. I need to be able to easily query by the id, show all, or pull a list per-user.

A hash map would work ok but seems inefficient when needing to pull a list based on conditions. I'm still fairly new to java, but not programming, is are there a better database system or something that would work better for my task?

Comment: You can try some simple file DBMS like SQLite

Comment: Is this a web app (i.e for Tomcat)? If so you could use the session to temporarily hold the data, it would be automatically cleared up when the session expires.

Comment: Beware of multi-threading issues.

Answer (score 3):

In-memory caches (without disk based stores) could be used - e.g. HazelCast/Redis/EHCache.  HazelCast has maps, multimaps, sets, lists, queues & topics (similar features are available in other in-memory stores).  You could also use in-memory database such as H2 etc. if you do not wish to use Java collections/in-memory caches.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an in memory database like [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/), that would give you the best of both worlds: direct integration into your app and the full power of a DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate imo. I am using java play framework and it uses H2 as database engine. It can run db on memory just like a normal database Engine (both HQL and SQL), doesnt require any DB server to be installed and if you want, you can also store the data on a simple file format.